# Is many-sorted logic compact?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I read [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3094712/understanding-sorts-in-many-sorted-logic-intuitively) earlier today. It contains [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3094712/understanding-sorts-in-many-sorted-logic-intuitively#comment6380682_3094750) by Noah Schweber, reproduced below, as well as [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3095636).

> "Many-sorted logic can be easily rewritten into standard (one sort) predicate logic with suitable predicates." This is mostly true, but misses an important subtlety: namely, compactness fails for many-sorted logic with infinitely many sorts, since "every element has a sort" isn't a first-order-expressible principle but is built into the semantics for many-sorted logic.

I'm having trouble understanding why the argument holds. In the course of attempting to write a proof that many-sorted logic is compact given that first-order logic is compact, I think I've grasped the point that Noah was making originally, namely that *the first-order equivalent of a many-sorted model may have domain elements with no sort (i.e. for which no sort predicate holds)*. I am failing, however, to see why this would make many-sorted logic non-compact. Intuitively, sortless entities seem like a kind of *dark matter* that doesn't interact with the semantics at all, since all functions, relations, constants, free, and bound variables are annotated with sorts and thus sortless entities never get a chance to influence the truth value of a well-formed formula.

So, **is many-sorted logic compact?** **What am I missing?**

---

**What follows is my attempt to prove that many-sorted logic is compact**

To make the intuition a little easier, let's assume that *I have at least one sort* and that *all sorts are nonempty*.

I'm pretty sure that *first-order logic is compact, regardless of the size of the signature*, even though you can do weird things with uncountable signatures like insist that the domain is uncountable using $\{c_\alpha \neq c_\beta : \alpha, \beta \in \kappa \land \alpha \neq \beta \}$ for some $|\kappa| > \omega$.

Let's assume I have a set of sentences in many-sorted logic that is finitely-satisfiable called $\Delta$. $\Delta$ might be satisfiable, it might not. At this point we don't know.

$\Delta$ can be converted into first-order logic (call the sentences $\Delta'$) by replacing each sort $S$ with a dedicated unary predicate $P$ and replacing quantifiers $[\forall x : S] ( \cdots )$ with circumlocutions like $[\forall x]( P(x) \to \cdots ) $ and then further insisting, for every distinct $i \neq j$, that $[\forall x](\lnot (P_i(x) \land P_j(x)))$. Additionally, for every function symbol, we have sentences asserting when their inputs have the correct sort, their output has the correct sort.

$\Delta$ is finitely satisfiable, so $\Delta'$ is finitely satisfiable. Thus $\Delta'$ is satisfiable. Thus $\Delta'$ has a model $M \models \Delta'$.

$M$ may contain what I will call *sortless garbage*, for which no unary-predicate-that's-a-sort-in-disguise $P$ holds.

Let $M'$ be the structure $M$ with all the sortless garbage removed. I claim that $M'$ is still a structure, i.e. none of the functions have become partial, because sortless garbage cannot be in the image of any function (this is where I'm using the assumption that all sorts are inhabited).

I claim that $M' \models \Delta'$ because all constant symbols refer to sorted entities and all quantifies are restricted to quantify exclusively over sorted entities.

$M'$ can be converted into $M''$, a many-sorted structure, in a straightforward way by interpreting the unary predicates as sorts again. For that many-sorted structure, $\Delta$ holds, as desired.